# OpenGL VBOs are slower than glDrawArrays

Tags: opengl, performance, optimization

So, this seems odd to me. I upload a large buffer of vertices, then every frame I call glBindbuffer and then the appropriate gl*Pointer functions with offsets into the buffer, then I use glDrawArrays to draw all of my triangles.

I'm only drawing about 100K triangles, however I'm getting about 15FPS.

This is where it gets weird, if I change it to not call glBindBuffer, then change the gl*Pointer calls to be actual pointers into the array I have in system memory, and then call glDrawArrays the same, my framerate jumps up to about 50FPS.

Any idea what I weird thing I could be doing that would cause this? Did I maybe forget to call glEnable(GL_ALLOW_VBOS_TO_RUN_FAST) or something?

Answer (score 2):

glBindBuffer is expensive, but not so much that you can expect a noticeable impact from a single bind (or several dozen of them, for that matter).

Did you check that you have the right usage flags when creating the buffer storage with glBufferData? For your scenario, GL_STATIC_DRAW is the ALLOW_IT_TO_RUN_FAST flag. If you accidentially use the wrong flags, it might do silly things with your buffer.

I've seen performance drop of nearly two full frames worth on a readback into a PBO once only because I used the wrong flags. When you get that one wrong, it is a "wtf, this cannot possibly take 30 ms???" experience.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using GL_Static_Draw, that's the sort of thing I thought it might be however.

Comment: A buffer holding 100k triangles, resp. 300k vertices should be no challenge to a somewhat modern graphics card, but ... what does glGet say on GL_MAX_ELEMENTS_VERTICES? I assume you're checking glGetError as standard procedure too?

Comment: 2048? I am also checking glGetError.

Comment: Doesn't that seem awfully small? This is on an i7 MacBook Pro, It's supposed to have nvidia graphics.

Comment: 2048 seems really really really awfully small. I would have expected a value of at least 128k on a somewhat elderly desktop or notebook, or 1-4M on a recent desktop. But, there is your explanation. The implementation is allowed to work "suboptimally" if you exceed this limit. Though, really... 2048. They can't be serious?

Comment: I haven't tested any PCs yet, but I did a survey of every Mac I could get my hands on, They all return 2048, regardless of video card. I wonder if there is some setting that could be limiting that.

Comment: My kind of old gf9800 says 1048576, which is what I would consider a "reasonable" value, too.

Comment: Just googling around, I found [this](http://www.myogl.org/?target=show&id=341) which seems to be a printout of the 330M (the discrete graphics in the 2010 MacBook Pro) and it says "GL_MAX_ELEMENTS_VERTICES: 1048576". Try installing gfxCardStatus and make sure your discrete card is being used and not the integrated Intel chip; that might actually explain the system memory being faster too, since the integrated chip leeches off of system memory (I think) and should therefore have fast access to it...

Comment: I'm not using a system with separate graphics, thus gfxCardStatus won't work on my computer. But I don't see GL_MAX_ELEMENTS_VERTICES higher then 2048 on *any* mac I've tested it on yet. Running the same problem on my pc gets me something in the range of 1Mil though.

Comment: If you have a mac, I wrote a test program to print out GL_MAX_ELEMENTS_VERTICES, feel free to give it a try: https://github.com/Arelius/glstat

Answer (score 1):

I think its a code specific problem not problem with VBOs..

- make sure you are not copying VBOs every time.
- make sure you are not misusing VBOs functions (I think there is a small difference between using VBOs in openGL 3.0 and previous versions).
- make sure that openGL is not generating an Error.
- debug your openGL code using gDebugger.

Comment: Copy them once, Additionally the code that runs to upload them is still getting uploaded, they are just going unused.

I've been debugging with gDebugger, no warnings or errors.

Comment: Look at the stats generated by gDebugger too - you may be doing something weird by mistake.

Comment: @Jari, nothing obvious.